# MingW with old winbase.h file

Tags: winapi, mingw

I want to use the function QueryFullProcessImageName from winbase.h in my Qt 4.8.1 app that uses the lastest MingW version (I downloaded it lately). The problem is that this function is quite new: it was introduced in Windows Vista and I'll guess it would be avaliable with such a new version of MingW, but it's not. Microsoft MSDN sad I needed to put the appropriate define in order for this function to be avaliable, but not only that didn't solve my problem, but I also can't find the function's declaration in winbase.h by Ctrl+F anyway.

Well, how can I solve this problem? I quite need that function :X

Just another insight to my problem: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53769-Mingw-included-in-Qt-installator-including-old-h-files

And a quite very interesting thing: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/browser/trunk/mingw-w64-headers/include/winbase.h?rev=5487 (it would seem that MingW does has the lastest winbase.h file, altought it didn't come with the installator)

My PC has a Windows 7 64-bit, while my Qt and Qt Creator is 32 bit.

Thanks,

Momergil

Comment: Would you mind switching to Cygwin? The latest one definitely has the function you want. From my experience, it has *much* more complete WinAPI headers than MinGW.

Comment: Also, note that the link you provided refers to a different project, [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/), which is a fork of MinGW. You may also want to try it out.

Comment: @Joulukuusi I gave a look and found no interest in Cygwin, but thanks for the advice. And yep, I noticed this thing about MiGW-w64, but I guessed that there should be a MinGW w32 with the function since it's not a exclusive 64bit one.

Comment: As their website states, MinGW-w64 provides "GCC for both x64 & x86 Windows". On the left side there's "WIN32 Downloads" link which is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @Joulukuusi thanks, but it wasn't good enough :P Qt Creator simply won't accept this compiler, don't know why, and it would seem that some files are missing (mingw32-make.exe, for example) or if they must be merged with the "natural" mingw, well there is not way of making it work here :T

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to (or can't) move to a version of MinGW that has `QyeryFullProcessImageName()` in its SDK headers, then you can add the following near the end of `winbase.h` (make sure it's before the closing brace of the `extern "C"` block):

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)

#define PROCESS_NAME_NATIVE 0x00000001

WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI QueryFullProcessImageNameA(
  HANDLE hProcess,
  DWORD dwFlags,
  LPSTR lpExeName,
  PDWORD lpdwSize
);

WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI QueryFullProcessImageNameW(
  HANDLE hProcess,
  DWORD dwFlags,
  LPWSTR lpExeName,
  PDWORD lpdwSize
);

#ifdef UNICODE
#define QueryFullProcessImageName QueryFullProcessImageNameW
#else
#define QueryFullProcessImageName QueryFullProcessImageNameA
#endif

#endif
```

If the API is in the libkernel32.a import library that should be all you need. The API was in the library for versions of MinGW 4.7.x that I have installed where it wasn't in the `winbase.h` header, so there's a good chance that all you'll need is the few lines of code from above.